# reporting verb + verb in -ing form

Tags: past-tense, reported-speech

I have a question regarding reporting verbs such as "deny", which are followed by another verb in -ing form.

Direct speech: "I didn't steal the car", said Harry.
The action is in the past tense "didn't steal".

So if I transformed this sentence into reported speech should it be "Harry denied stealing the car" or "Harry denied having stolen the car"?

Comment: Both your transformations into "reported speech" are fine, but I can't think of any context where the Perfect version (***having stolen*** rather than ***stealing***) usefully adds anything to the meaning, AND it sounds a bit dated / formal to me. So I suggest you don't bother with that one (apart from being prepared to accept it from *others*). Here's [the relevant usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=denied+stealing%2Cdenied+having+stolen&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10)

Answer (score 1):

> Harry denied stealing the car.

sounds simpler and better to me. You can say

> Harry denied having stolen the car

when you want to stress the action and/or you don't know exactly when it happened.

You can also say

> Harry denied that he stole the car.